# libquadmath and GNU-gsl ode solver?

Tags: precision, gsl, floating-point-precision

I would like a working precision of 40 or more decimal places whilst solving an ODE.
Could anyone tell me if it is possible to get higher precision results using the gsl ODE solver, perhaps using libquadmath? It looks from the gsl_odeiv2 documentation over at http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref.html#Driver that they only take doubles, but is this really the case?

If not could anyone suggest an alternative? Does something like 'odeint' support higher than double precision? Do I have to write my own from scratch?

(For reference my specific problem is at: [Writing Runge-Kutta ODE solver using gsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053768/writing-runge-kutta-ode-solver-using-gsl), now with the bug fixed thanks to Daniel Fischer)

Comment: Have you tried [odeint](http://odeint.com)? It is a c++ lib which supports multi-precision types.

Comment: I had just stumbled across that actually. Does it support quad precision? I can't quite seem to see the mention on the documentation, but that would be great if it does..

Comment: I don't know quad precision. But odeint is quite flexibly. if quad precision supports operators +-*/ I would expect that odeint can handle it. For example, it supports boost.multiprecision out of the box.

Comment: Silly question but how do I install odeint? It says just to include the header, which I have done, but even when I put the whole unzipped download in /usr/local/include which is in my search path it has trouble finding files. Also if I put my code in the unzipped folder and try compiling it also says various files not found. Finally doing -I/absolutepath/boost/numeric/odeit on compilation doesn't solve it..

Comment: In your words it must be -I/absolutepath

Comment: Ah, thanks. So regards to getting higher precision how would one do this with boost.multiprecision? e.g. taking your harmonic osc ex on website can I just change the types of things, like state vector, from `double` to something else more precise? I had originally though of using `lquadmath`, and `__float128` but I guess that won't work. I don't know much (anything) about boost though so would appreciate any info or links on that.

Comment: I would try so define the state_type as an array or vector of your multiprecion type and the value_type is the multiprecision type:

typedef your_mulitprec_type value_type;
typedef vector< value_type > state_type;
runge_kutta4< state_type , value_type > stepper;

Just try, if is works with __float128 otherwise use a type from boost.multiprecion.

Comment: I tried replacing a few doubles in the example code with `_float128` but generates errors on compile even when linked with lquadmath. Sorry to be a pain but where can I read about these supported boost high precision types? I've tried googling boost multi-precision etc but not getting anything..

Comment: [boost.multiprecision](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/big_number/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) It is not an official boost library, but will be included in near future into boost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18634/discussion-between-fpghost-and-headmyshoulder)